# Typescript, await for function

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-s3

Im trying to upload files to S3 bucket using typescript and aws-sdk package. The ideal outcome is:
 Upload to s3 is successful THEN => Load SQS message.

Here is the function for reading file recieved and executing s3Upload

```
        // on each byte of uploading
        file.on("data", function (data) {
            console.log("File [" + fieldname + "] got " + data.length + " bytes");
        });
        // whenever the upload is finished into this microservice
        file.on("end", function () {
            console.log("File [" + fieldname + "] Finished uploading");

        });
        const s3BucketLink = await saveToS3(filename, file);

### HERE IS IMPORTANT, I BASICALLY WANT TO CONFIRM THAT STATUS IS 200 and only then upload to SQS

        if (s3BucketLink.status === 200) {
            console.log("its done");
        }
        console.log("here");
        console.log(s3BucketLink);
    });
```

and in my saveToS3 I have this

```
    interface S3Response {
        status: number;
        filepath: string;
    }

    export const saveToS3 = async (filename: string, file: any): Promise<S3Response> => {
        let status = {
            status: 400,
            filepath: ""
        };
        s3.listBuckets(function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error", err);
            } else {
                console.log("Success", data.Buckets);
            }
        });

        const params = {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: filename, // File name you want to save as in S3
            Body: file
        };
        s3.upload(params, function (err: Error, data: any) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
            status = {
                status: 200,
                filepath: data.Location
            };

        });
        return status;


    };
```

Im basically trying to set the status 200 and if its the case then go ahead and load sqs.

The current results in console.log would look like this

```
[Function]
File [File] got 65002 bytes
here
{ status: 400 }
File [File] got 65536 bytes
File [File] got 65536 bytes
File [File] got 65536 bytes
File [File] got 65536 bytes
File [File] got 65536 bytes
File [File] got 65536 bytes
File [File] got 65536 bytes
File [File] got 65536 bytes
File [File] got 65536 bytes
File [File] got 65536 bytes
File [File] got 43814 bytes
File [File] Finished uploading
Success [ { Name: 'name', CreationDate: 2020-05-31T06:50:22.000Z } ]
File uploaded successfully. https://name.s3.amazonaws.com/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3
```

Would really appreciate any help on how to achieve the desired outcome :)

Comment: `return status;` in `saveToS3` is executed before `s3.upload()` has done its job.

Comment: so how can i make it wait? what would be the work  around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got a couple of issues here.

You're executing a couple of asynchronous methods (`s3.listBuckets` and `s3.upload`) without waiting for them to complete. So you are starting those actions and then calling `return status;`, which is why you're getting that value back early before the file has finished uploading. You'll need to wait for those things to complete before returning.

But both of these methods use callbacks, not promises, and you want your `saveToS3` method to return a `Promise`. So you'll need to wrap both of those method calls. Here's a simplified example of what that looks like (with some code omitted). In this example the method returns a `Promise` which is only resolved when the callback of `s3.upload` is fired, meaning that operation has completed or returned an error.

```js
export const saveToS3 = (filename: string, file: any): Promise<S3Response> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.upload(params, function (err: Error, data: any) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(status);
    });
  });
}
```

This will cause any `await saveToS3()` statement to wait for the operation to complete.

Comment: you are the man :) thank you, its a good refresher back to JS world :). Totally slipped my mind... there is even a "util" package in node that can help you wrap those functions in promises. Thanks again, apprecaite it :)